# Easy way for simultaneous record/playback iOS

Tags: ios, core-audio

I have tried implementing this using audio queues in vain. The input queue would stop running as soon as my output queue started making calls to its callback. Is there something I am missing? Or will I end up having to dig around in audio units and remote i/o.